# Как с помощью команды bat узнать место расположение exe'шника конкретного процесса?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, процесс

Мне необходимо с помощью команды в bat получить местоположение уже запущенного процесса, чтобы далее использовать полученную с этого действия переменную.

Подробнее:
Мне нужно получить весь путь расположения процесса steam.exe (пробовал через `tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq Steam.exe"`, но пути к файлу там не указывается), чтобы в последствии запустить этот процесс с дополнительным параметром. Я знаю, что можно указать фиксированный путь, но вопрос именно в том, каким образом этот путь можно получить из самого процесса.

Comment: подозреваю, что только писать собственную утилиту. Вот, к примеру, как тут: http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=54195

Answer (score 1):

2 способа, через утилиты **wmic** и **where**:

```
@for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%i in ('@wmic process where "name='steam.exe' and not executablepath=null" get ExecutablePath /format:list^|find/i"="') do @echo %%j
```

и

```
where steam
```

2-ой способ не требует проверки на то, запущен ли процесс, а ищет исходя из параметров среды.

Comment: Второй способ выдал ошибку "_INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)_". `Where`, кстати, вообще немного из другой оперы - вопрос был про запущенный процесс. Первый способ ошибки не выдал, но вместо пути написал "C:\Program", то есть путь с пробелом он обрабатывать не умеет. Учитывая, что в вопросе речь про .exe, который сидит в "Program Files", решением это назвать сложно. Исправьте код на рабочий, уберу минус.

Comment: Да пофик, на минус. А вот код не рассчитан на использование длинных путей с пробелами- "косяк". Код изменен.